# No results for path in JSON using JsonPath

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I have the following simple JSON file for unit testing purposes:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "firstname": "testname",
  "lastname": "testlastname",
  "username": "testusername",
  "password": "testpassword",
  "email": "test@host.com",
  "organization": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "testcompany"
  }
}
```

I use a mapper `String json = MAPPER.writeValueAsString(expected);`
and I to get the variables by using JsonPath.read.

It works fine for all variables f.e. `JsonPath.read(json, "$.firstname")`.

When it comes to `JsonPath.read(json, "$.organization")` though, I receive `com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: No results for path: $['organization']`

I have also tried using something like `JsonPath.read(json, (int) "$.organization.id")` similarly I get `Missing property in path`

Any thoughts on what might cause the issue?

Comment: Have you tried `JsonPath.read(json,"$..id")`

Comment: This returns the id of the base object. I tried JsonPath.read(json, "$.*.id") though and it returns empty array.

Comment: Have you also tried `$['organization']['id']`, ps: what is the exact content of the `json` string ?

Comment: Did you try to reformat your JSON so the contents of organization are wrapped in quotes? "organization": "{ ... }"